# Laravel - Nested Relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-9, laravel-relations

I'm learning Laravel and need to get a list of nested relationships. My foreign keys seem to be set up correctly.

```
products->servers->configs
```

**Product Controller**

```
$products = Product::with('servers')->get();
```

**Product Model**

```
 public function servers()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Config::class, Server::class);
    }
```

I'm only getting a list of servers that are the configs. Eg

```
products:{
  id:1,
  servers:[
    ram:16gb //this is the config not the server
 ]
}
```

How can I get the list of configs inside the servers inside the products? Eg

```
products:{
  id:1,
  server:{
    id:1,
    name:'big server',
    config:{
     ram:16gb
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Product** Modal Use `hasMany` Method

```
public function servers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Server::class);
    }
```

In **Server** Modal Use `hasMany(for many rows get)` or `hasOne(for single row get)` method

```
 public function configs()
 {
       return $this->hasMany(Config::class);
 } 

 public function config()
 {
        return $this->hasOne(Config::class);
 }
```

Now In `ProuctController` [see](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading) how to get nested relationship data

```
 $products = Product::with('servers.configs')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks....I also went servers() in my product model return $this->hasMany(Server::class)->with('config');. It would be better get what you need from the controller rather than the model?

Comment: @ottz0 `return $this->hasMany(Server::class)->with('config');`: you shouldn't do that! Now every time you use the `servers` relation you'll automatically load the `config` models even if you don't want to thus having unecessary `DB` queries and unecessary processing on the `Eloquent` side to prepare those `config` models for you. It's better to load the relation only when needed.